# How to remove all punctuations,specials characters in CSV and replace numbers with "number" string?

Tags: python, csv

I am outputting the data from 2 columns in a new CSV . I am experiencing difficulties with replacing the numbers in the columns with "number" string and removing all the punctuation and special characters. Tried with `string.punctuation`, didn't help me a lot or at least I didn't use it well...

This is my code until now:

EDIT:

```
import csv
import re


cols = [0, 7]  # column index numbers to be extracted
extracted = []

with open('data.csv', newline='') as csvfin:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvfin, delimiter=',', quotechar='"',
                           quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    with open('output.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfout:
        csvWriter = csv.writer(csvfout, delimiter=',', quotechar='"',
                               quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        for row in csvReader:
                for col_num in cols:
                    extracted.append(row[col_num].lower())
                    extracted = re.sub(r'[,.:@#?!&$]', ' ', extracted)
                    extracted = [re.sub('\d+', 'number', change) for change in extracted]
                csvWriter.writerow(extracted)
                extracted = []
```

Comment: Just a note, you can use multiple things using `with`. So instead of having 2 nested `with` statements you can use one. `with open('data.csv', 'r', newline='')  as csvfin, open('newfile.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfout:`

Comment: Have you run this chunk of code? What is the output currently - does it return a `TypeError`? What are you expecting in that output csv?

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: See the [mcve] guidelines.  It is unclear what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleted my old answer, I sort of misunderstood what you are asking. Not sure what you mean by replace numbers with "number" string, but this will work to remove punctuation from the list of extracted text.

change the line

`extracted = re.sub(r'[,.:@#?!&$]', ' ', extracted)`

to

`extracted = [re.sub([,.:@#?!&$], ' ', text) for text in extracted]`

Explanation of what that change does:

Since `re.sub` doesn't accept a list loop through the strings in `extracted` calling `re.sub` on each string, this is done through a list comprehension, which I recommend looking into if they're new to you. The "cleaned" list is then assigned back to `extracted`.

Comment: That worked! About replacing the numbers I am trying to replace every number in csv for example `231321312` will be replaced with the string `"number"`, not sure how I can approach this yet.

Comment: That could be accomplished in a similar way to the punctuation removal, looping over the list using a regex pattern that matches any set of numbers, replacing each with `'number'`. Check out python's docs on the re module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for some more insight on just how to do that. If you still are having trouble edit your answer with what you have so far in and I'd be happy to help.

Comment: Thank you, was really helpful! I editted with the final code.